# VSFTPD Configuration

Tags: ftp

In my config file, I have

local_root=/home/$USER

but $USER doesn't seem to give me the user's login name. It's taking it as literally $USER when I attempt to login and fails to change to that directory.

Comment: What distro are you using? Any logs in /var/log/daemon or /var/log/messages or /var/log/vsftpd.log pertaining to vsftpd ?

Comment: I'm using Jaunty Ubuntu. I'll get back to you on the logs issue - I won't be able to touch the ftp service till after a user uploads their files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to chroot users into their home directories; try this in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` instead:

```
chroot_local_user=yes
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
```

I found it a bit unintuitive that the sample config for CentOS (quoted above) refers to `chroot_local_user`, but doesn't actually provide it in the config file.

Update: to explain a bit more:

If `chroot_local_user=yes` then users get chroot'd to their home directories UNLESS they are listed in `chroot_list_file` (in which case they have normal access to the entire file system).

If `chroot_local_user=no` then users do NOT get chroot'd to their home directories UNLESS they are listed in `chroot_list_file` (in which case, they do get chroot'd).

So to chroot by default (which sounded like what you were trying to accomplish), set `chroot_local_user=yes`. List any exceptions (users you do not want chroot'd) in `chroot_list_file`.

Note that you do not have to list users without FTP access in this file in either case.

Comment: So the list is a list of users not to chroot? 

I would like to create a directory structure that is not based on the normal HOME directory of Linux. Instead, I'm looking for something like /var/www/sites/$USER ?? If I can specify them in a list, would it just be key-value pairs? Thanks!

Comment: are they ftp only users or do they need shell access? If the former ... just set their home directory to /var/www/sites/$USER (not the variable but the actual user name